# How to get GL/gl.h

Tags: opengl

My Operating system is Ubuntu 11. When I want to run **./mkmkfiles.imake** ,it didn't find **GL/gl.h**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install the MESA packages development headers :

```
apt-get install mesa-common-dev
```

You can check wether this package provide the files you are looking for using dpkg :

```
dpkg -L mesa-common-dev
```

You can also look for packages that provides this file using apt-file :

```
apt-file search GL/gl.h
```